# How to find out exactly what is changeing in $scope.$watch

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to find out exactly what on my page I need to watch before applying a specific filter/conversion to it. To do this I am using a $watch so that I will know this value has been set/what sets it. The problem is I don’t know exactly which variable to watch for in the $scope.$watch as I am using external libraries that load and set the variables.

How can I print out or find out exactly which variables are being watched in the watch function. I currently have the following:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  console.log("Variable Set");
})
```

How could I do something like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  console.log("watching: " + scopeItemModified);
})
```

so that when I click on an item on my webpage I can see exactly what is being changed/watched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No to print the same variable is not possible simply but you can watch whole scope like this.

```
  $scope.$watchCollection(function(){return $scope;},function(n,o){
    alert(o);
  })
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do watch one variable of your scope, and it will be something like this:

```
$scope.nameOfVariableInScope = '';

$scope.$watch('nameOfVariableInScope', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log('Lets see the new value and the old value of my variable:');
      console.log(newValue, oldValue);
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I understand this concept but if you don't add 'nameOfVariableInScope' to the $watch you can actually watch every change in the scope. I will eventually add that so I only listen to a specific variable but for now I do not know what the variable I am meant to be listening to is. I would like to use the watch to find that variable

Comment: hmm i see... then $watchCollection() using your scope object or using $scope.myVars may solve your problem, watching the full object

Answer (score 0):

With this (really) strange angular hack I think it can solve your problem...

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.first = '1';
    $scope.second = '2';
    $scope.objectField = {
        third: '3'
    };
    
    var scopeCloned = {}
    
    $scope.$watchCollection(
        function(scope) {
            
            //We compare each scope fields previoulsy copied
            //If there is a change, we save that in console
            angular.forEach(scope, function(value, key) {
                if(key.substring(0, 1) != '$' && key != 'this') {
                    if(!angular.equals(scopeCloned[key],value)) {
                        var changes = {
                            field: key,
                            prevValue: scopeCloned[key],
                            newValue: value
                        }
                        console.log(changes);
                    }
                }
            });
            
            //We copy scope fields (without angular fields) to compare next time
            angular.forEach(scope, function(value, key) {
                if(key.substring(0, 1) != '$' && key != 'this') {
                 scopeCloned[key] = angular.copy(value);
                }
            });
        }, function() {}
    );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="first"/><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="second"/><br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="objectField.third"/><br>
</div>
```